# php-fpm (7.1.6) Doesn't turn on display_errors

Tags: php, apache

System:
Debian Jessie
PHP-FPM 7.1.6
Apache 2.4.10
XDebug 2.5.4

PHP Won't display Parse and other fatal errors, while my `php.ini` clearly states `display_errors = On`. On the `phpinfo()` page, it says `display_errors` `Off`. It parses the correct Ini file and no additional ini files that could have overridden it.

`error_reporting` is set to E_ALL.

a `grep display_errors` of the ini file doesn't show any other setting than it turning on.

Am I missing something?

Comment: phpinfo differentiates between a master value and a local value.  Are master and local off, or is master on but local off?

Comment: Some code might be calling `ini_set('display_errors', '0');`

Comment: @ConorMancone Both are Off.

Comment: @ShiraNai7 I am quite sure nothing in runtime is turning it off.

Comment: What OS are you running?

Comment: @ConorMancone Debian 8 jessie.

Answer (score 0):

if display_errors shows On in your php.ini and phpinfo() shows off for the master value then there is definitely a problem somewhere in your configuration files (or a bug in PHP 7.1.6, but that is probably less likely).

It sounds like you've already checked all the details but it is worth double checking.  In particular this is the list of items I would verify:

1. Verify that the php.ini file referenced in your phpinfo() results (under `Loaded Configuration File`) matches the actual location of the php.ini file you are editing.  Some systems might have more than one and I've been fooled by that before.
2. Also make sure and grep the directory specified by `Scan this dir for additional .ini files`.  If a file in there sets the display_errors directive (unlikely but possible) it will override anything in your php.ini file.
3. Check for configuration directives in .htaccess files.  These can also set the display_errors value.  I'm pretty sure that when they do so they set the local value, not the master value, but I'm not 100%: it wouldn't hurt to check.  (although this probably doesn't apply to PHP-FPM, so I guess I'm just mentioning this for completeness).
4. I know it is silly, but just double check that your `display_errors = On` line isn't commented out.

I'm not aware of any other places that PHP configuration options might be set, but it could be that there are more obscure ones out there: a quick search for setting php.ini values via (system) environment variables didn't show up anything.  That would be a good way to override settings without realizing it.

Comment: `phpinfo()` shows no other config files parsed and the correct ini file. the additional .ini file directory is set to (none). there are no .htaccess files anywhere in the tree. I have checked with a Syntax Highlighter, display_errors is not commented out.

Comment: That sounds very fishy to me.  Not that this is a definite sign of trouble, but I don't think I have ever once seen a distribution with additional .ini files turned off like that.  That is set at compile/build time, and it is very common for installed modules to need their own individual config files.  Definitely not 100% sure, but I'm starting to think you might have troubles with your build/installation.  How did you install 7.1?  I'm guessing it isn't the default that comes with Debian 8 (although I could be wrong).

Comment: I compiled it on that VM with [This configuration](https://hastebin.com/ereleponog.pl) since somehow Apt couldn't find the package, even after using ondrej/php and changing to the correct repo. (since that'll throw an error with jessie). [Hastebin link to the HTML of phpinfo()](https://hastebin.com/amopawirey.xml)

Comment: I've tried to install the binary from https://packages.sury.org/php and that has fixed it. I think there was indeed something wrong with my build.

Comment: Glad it's working.  Obviously this was one of those tricky ones.

Answer (score 0):

If your changes in `/etc/php/7.1/fpm/php.ini` are not reflected in your current PHP settings, e.g. phpinfo(), after restarting your HTTP server -like you were used to-, this may be because restarting the server does not restart the actual PHP subsystems, which are running in their own processes/sockets, hence the FPM thingy.

You want to restart PHP like this :

`sudo systemctl restart php7.1-fpm`

This is of course applicable to other PHP versions, just replace 7.1 by whatever version number X.Y .